# Show all available triplets on server

Tags: vcpkg

Commnad below show 7zip library available on server:

```
vcpkg search 7zip
```

How to list all available triplets on remote?

Answer (score 3):

vcpkg triplets are configurations that specify how to build a package for a target environment (OS-architecture-linkage).

The term triplet is a bit confusing, since there can be more to a triplet than these 3 values. For instance target compiler or whether or not the crt is linked dynamically or statically.

The informal way to view the available triplets that ship with vcpkg is:

`vcpkg install 7zip --triplet=""`

The install command will then list available triplets.